# Overwriting Shellcode with read() Syscall?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, shellcode

I am trying to get past a rather complex shellcode filter, and to do so I am using a multi-stage shellcode injection. For my first stage, I have the following:

```
.global _start
_start:
.intel_syntax noprefix

        mov rax, 0
        mov rdi, 0
        lea rsi, [rip+10]  
        mov rdx, 1000
        syscall
```

this calls `read(0, rip+10, 1000)` which is supposed to read additional shellcode from stdin, and inserts it after the syscall, however I am getting a

```
read(0, 0x401018, 1000)                 = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
```

when executed. I have compiled with

```
gcc -Wl,-N --static -nostdlib -o stage1 stage1.s
```

and extracted the raw .text section with

```
objcopy --dump-section .text=stage1-opcodes --writable-text stage1
```

which should make the .text section of the code writeable. I am not sure what else I need to do to ensure that the memory address `[rip+10]` is accessible and doesn't throw a bad address error.

Comment: That `gcc` command won't assemble that asm source.  You're missing a `.intel_syntax noprefix` directive, so who knows what else you might have left out from a [mcve]?

Comment: Also, that RIP-relative offset leaves a 1-byte gap after `syscall`.  Check your code with `objdump -drwC -Mintel`.  So even if you fixed the permission problem, it would break.  Use a label for the RIP-relative address target like a normal person, that's what labels are for.  Then you can optimize to `mov edx, 1000` or something shellcode-compatible (avoiding `0` bytes) without having to fix the hard-coded offset again.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry, I didn't include the .intel_syntax noprefix but it is a part of my code. I've updated the question to include my header.

Comment: Works for me when I assemble + link it with that exact GCC command, on Arch GNU/Linux.  Then run `strace ./stage1` in a terminal.  `read()` waits for input, then returns success.  I get SIGSEGV after typing in "alkfg".  (`read` returns 5).  I didn't use `objcopy` because you already have a working static executable with nmagic (writeable text) from GCC output.  For injecting as shellcode, assuming you injected into a page with write+exec permission to make code injection possible in the first place, then of course it works.